# Ask.fm node api cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

So I am new to node.js. And I found this Ask.fm api And I am trying to run it. Now what do I put in ? I have downloaded npm cookie and included require('cookie') as well but it still gives this error :

```
askFm {
cookie: undefined,
_loggedIn: false,
lastError: null,
last_cookies: null }
```

Here is how I am using it.

```
const askFM=require('askfm-node-api')
let cookie="<cookie string>"
let ask=new askFM(cookie)
```

Here is the url of site that I downloaded the api from :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/askfm-node-api

Comment: I suppose you added a cookie?

Comment: The you need to use the cookie constructor to get a new cookie and then pass a cookie as a string to the variable cookie you created..

Answer (score 0):

Hello I'm the one who developed the npm module.. so ask.fm login cookie is what gets saved in the browser after you login with your account .. you can get the cookie string simply by going to `ask.fm` login then choose `inspect element` and press on the network tab.. on the left choose any call then scroll down to the request headers on the right you'll see a propery `cookie:` take whats after it.. now you got your cookie string [See the long string after Cookie: here is your string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2mEB.png)

Note that once you log out the is string will be no longer valid.. so the best option is the save the string then clear you site settings to protect the session you have